# Find two Sylow $3$-subgroups of $S_4$, $P$ and $Q$ and show that they are conjugate by finding an element $g\in S_4$ such that $P=gQg^{−1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

The task is:

> Find two Sylow $3$-subgroups of $S_4$, $P$ and $Q$ and show that they are conjugate by finding an element $g\in S_4$ such that $P=gQg^{−1}$.

I realize that they must be conjugate by Sylow theorems, but I'm having trouble finding an element such that $\langle (1,2,3) \rangle$ is conjugate to $\langle (2,3,4) \rangle$

**Do I just brute force all elements? There must be a better way of finding this.**

**Also, is there a way of finding all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_n$ efficiently?**

I'd appreciate the help since these kinds of questions seem to keep coming up on exams, but I feel like I would blunder it if I went the brute-force way.

Comment: Sylow was a person, his name is written with a capital S.Also "i" is probably a person, so it is written as I.

Comment: [This](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_Permutations_have_Same_Cycle_Type) might help.

Comment: Since all Sylow p-subgroups are conjugate, you can work out your task in a different direction: choose some Sylow p-subgroup (e.g. your $Q=\langle (1,2,3)\rangle$) and choose some element $g\in S_4$, then calculate $P=gQg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$(14)(123)(14)^{-1}=(1)(234),$$ the element you're looking for is $(14)$.

---

[Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_Permutations_have_Same_Cycle_Type) is a lemma that will help you answer similar questions.

Comment: For the second question, would it suffice to consider the cycles with $|n=p^k|$ elements(so all n-cycles) for some |p^k| being the order of a Sylow p subgroup?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, @Hristmar, yes, you're right; it follows from Sylow's first theorem.